# Как запрашивать корректный путь к файлу? Python

Tags: python, ввод

```
import sys
import os
class Notepad()
    x = str()
    y = str()
    def save(self):
    print('''Введите путь файла для копирования - c:\\''afs''\\''asdffads''\\''корректный путь''')
    text1 = sys.stdin.readline()
    if text1 == ('Здесь должен быть указан корректный путь, если он корректный то открывает этот путь, например \\с:\\user\\итд, как сделать'):
        for text1 in range(''): #здесь ошибка, не знаю как сделать
            x = open(text1, 'r') 
            filetext1 = x.read()
    else:
        print('Выводит сообщение что неправильно ввели путь и возвращает на строку 7-8, как сделать')
    print('''Введите путь файла для создания, в который хотите скопировать - c:\\''afs''\\''asdffads''\\''корректный путь''')
    text2 = sys.stdin.readline()
    if text2 == ('Здесь должен быть указан корректный путь, если он корректный то открывает этот путь, например \\с:\\user\\итд, как сделать'):
        for text2 in range (''): #здесь ошибка, не знаю как сделать
            y = open(text2, 'w') 
            text2 = y.write(filetext1)
            x.close()
            y.close()
            y = open(text2, 'r')
            filetext2 = y.read()
            print(filetext2) #выводит содержимое второго файла с информацией откопированной из первого
    else:
        print('Выводит сообщение что неправильно ввели путь и возвращает на строку 7-8, как сделать')
```

Здравствуйте, учусь программировать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хочу прогу сделать, которая принимает значение пути первого файла, обрабатывает его, затем принимает значение пути второго файла, который нужно создать и откопировать в него значения из первого. Файлы текстовые. Как сделать, чтобы программа понимала корректный ввод пути к файлу? Как сделать возврат из определенной точки кода в нужную, использующуюся ранее? Прогу хотелось бы оставить в таком виде, так как другие виды я пока не понимаю. Модули можно добавлять другие. Поправьте, пожалуйста, ошибки, спасибо.

**UPDATE:**

```
import os
class Notepad:
    def open():
        while True:
            firstfile = input('Введите путь файла для копирования ')
            if os.path.exists(firstfile):
                print('Копируем file'.format(firstfile))
                text1 = open(firstfile, 'r') 
                filetext1 = text1.read()
                text1.close()
                break
        else:
            print('Неудалось найти файл'.format(firstfile))
    def create():
        while True:
            secondfile = input('Создайте файл с необходимым путем')
            if os.path.exists(secondfile):
                print('Создаем новый файл'.format(secondfile))
                text2 = open(secondfile, 'w') 
                filetext2 = text2.write(filetext1)
                filetext2.close()
                break
        else:
            print('Неудалось создать файл'.format(secondfile))
    def opennew():
        while True:
            if os.path.exists(secondfile):
                text2 = open(secondfile, 'r')
                filetext2 = y.read()
                print(filetext2)
                break
```

Такой код сделал, оформил в виде классов и функций. Запускаю в питон - все норм. Потом обращаюсь к функции open() и выдает ошибку. Почему так? Что подправить? Про что почитать?

```
>>> open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    open()
TypeError: Required argument 'file' (pos 1) not found
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        filepath_old = input( 'Введите путь файла для копирования: ' )
        if os.path.exists( filepath_old ):
            print( 'Копируем содержимое файла: {}'.format( filepath_old ) )
            file_old = open( filepath_old, 'r' )
            text_old = file_old.read()
            file_old.close()
            break
        else:
            print( 'Не удалось найти файл: {}'.format( filepath_old ) )

    while True:
        filepath_new = input( 'Введите путь файла в который хотите скопировать {}: '.format( filepath_old ) )
        try:
            file_new = open( filepath_new, 'w' ) # 'w' - если файл существует, то будет очищен | 'a' - пишет в конец файла
            file_new.write( text_old )
            file_new.close()
            print( 'Содержимое файла: {} сопированно в: {}'.format( filepath_old, filepath_new ) )
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print( e )
    exit()
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import os

class notepad:
    files = {}

    def __init__( self ):
        print( 'Какие файлы копируем?' )
        while True:
            filepath = input( 'Укажите полное имя файла: ' )
            r = self.new( filepath )
            if r:
                print( 'Файл {} добавлен.'.format( filepath ) )
            else:
                print( 'Не удалось найти файл: {}'.format( filepath ) )

            r = input( 'Добавить еще один файл? ( Y / Д / 1 | N / Н / 0 ): ' ).lower()
            if r == 'y' or r == 'д' or r == 1:
                pass
            elif r == 'n' or r == 'н' or r == 0:
                break

        print( 'Куда копируем?' )
        while True:
            filepath = input( 'Укажите полное имя файла: ' )
            try:
                file = open( filepath, 'w' ) # 'w' - если файл существует, то будет очищен | 'a' - пишет в конец файла
                for i in self.files:
                    file.write( '{}\n'.format( self.files[i].read() ) )
                    print( 'Содержимое файла: {} сопированно в: {}'.format( i, filepath ) )
                    self.files[i].close()
                file.close()
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print( e )
            break

    def new( self, filepath ):
        if os.path.exists( filepath ):
            if not self.files.get( filepath ):
                self.files[filepath] = open( filepath, 'r' )
            return True
        else:
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    notepad = notepad()
```

Ваша ошибка возникает из за того что вы пытаетесь открыть файл, а не вызвать функцию из класса Notepad. Для того что бы вызвать функцию из класса, его нужно объявить.

```
имя_переменной = имя_класса()
имя_переменной.имя_функции()
```

Comment: спасибо, очень круто!

Comment: какая книга научила вас так быстро ориентироваться?

Comment: Этот код вы сами написали? Можете, пожалуйста, если вас не затруднит, описать ход ваших мыслей при решении этого вопроса.